# Onchange event between drop down list and mobile field

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone tell how is it done in javascript 
We have drop down list of citys
London 
New York 
Mumbai
When I select London 
It show " 11111"
In mobile input field And so on
Every time I change the city show the number of that city which belongs to them

Comment: You should add some  of your HTML and  JavaScript if  you have any, it makes it easier  to help  you.

Comment: Here is the mdn official doc which can help, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Answer (score 0):

This is how `change` event works with `select`

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
   <option value="Audi">Audi
   <option value="BMW">BMW
   <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
   <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>


 function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    alert(x) //here x shows the selected value
 }
```